# Array pointing to a null position after being passed to another class, Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception, label

I'm having this strange problem with my code, I've made a array of labels so that when I pass the array to another class this one can read and know the position of the label I want to move and change it's position, I've tried with prints all over the place to know what the array is passing, before passing the array to the other class I placed a print, the print in that moment has the correct information but when I tell the button to call the method from my other class and passes it, I get a NullPointerException.

That's how I make the array

```
JLabel[] listabolaslabels ;


    Partida partida;


    public Gui() {
        initComponents();
        //partida = new Partida();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable( false );



        this.listabolaslabels = new JLabel[]{

            //Bolas Nivel 1, Jugador 1
            this.bolaj1,
            this.nivel1j1bola1,
            this.nivel1j1bola2,
            this.nivel1j1bola3,
            //Bolas Nivel 2, Jugador 1
            this.nivel2j1bola1,
            this.nivel2j1bola2,
            this.nivel2j1bola3,
            //Bolas Nivel 3, Jugador 1
            this.nivel3j1bola1,
            this.nivel3j1bola2,
            this.nivel1j1bola3,


            //Bola Comodin
            this.labelcomodin,


            //Bolas Nivel 1, Jugador 2
             this.nivel1j2bola1,
            this.nivel1j2bola2,
            this.nivel1j2bola3,
            //Bolas Nivel 2, Jugador 2
            this.nivel2j2bola1,
            this.nivel2j2bola2,
            this.nivel2j2bola3,
            //Bolas Nivel 3, Jugador 12
            this.nivel3j2bola1,
            this.nivel3j2bola2,
            this.nivel3j2bola3};

    }
```

There is the code that the button executes

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.out.println(listabolaslabels[0]);

When the program get's to this point it shows the nullpointerexception
        partida.getlista(listabolaslabels[0]);

    }
```

Meanwhile in the other class, in this case "Partida"

```
public void getlista(JLabel lista){
        //System.out.println(lista);
    }
```

That's the method, I'm using to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have misidentified the source of your error. You declare the field `partida` but do not initialize it anywhere. This field is initialized to `null` by default.

Make sure that `partida` is not `null` before attempting to call its `getlista()` method, or you will get an NPE.

You haven't shown all your code so it may be the case that you do set `partida` to something somewhere, but you should verify that it is actually not `null` at the point where you are getting the NPE.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem, now I only have to fix that when I call the method the label moves till the end, it doesn't move with motion.

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but: Consider using a `List` instead of a fixed array, e.g. an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`. A `List` has `get()`, `remove()`, and `add()` which you can use to perform your move operation. If you're still having trouble with your move logic (fixed array or not), feel free to post it as a new question.

Comment: Sure I'll do it, one more question, do you have any kind of site where I can get a good example of how to make a list, I had many troubles making the array, Thank you very much :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html (there is a specific section on Lists on the left hand nav menu) or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_list_interface.htm (short and to the point).